# Can clang format format C/C++ functions to break argument lists before the comma?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I've noticed you can do this.

From https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#

> BCIS_BeforeComma (in configuration: BeforeComma) Break constructor initializers before the colon and commas, and align the commas with the colon.

to get the following effect

```
Constructor()
    : initializer1()
    , initializer2()
```

I'd like to similarly be able to break

```
foo(a,b,c,d,e)
```

to

```
foo
  ( a
  , b
  , c
  , d
  , e
  );
```

is this possible?

It seems there is such an option with the [resharper formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_CPP_CppWrappingPageScheme.html) for C/C++. Search for `Prefer wrap before ","` on the page.

Comment: I never claimed there were. The question is about formatting argument lists but I used the example of constructor initialisier formatting from clang to show the kind of style that I would appreciate.

Comment: clang format can format C but the only example I've found for comma first breaks is with C++ constructor lists. It is given as an example. If you can suggest some better wording to clarify I can adjust.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: Is ` AlignAfterOpenBracket` option not suitable for you?

Comment: @P.W That puts the comma at the end of the line as far as I can tell.